# check if a form field has changed using a play Form object

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

Is there any way to check directly, if the content of a form field in play framework has changed?

for example my `Device.java` is something like this:

```
class Device{
  String name;
  String type;}
```

and then somewhere in my controller, I have a form of type Device. is there any way to check using `boundForm` if the value of the `name` property has changed?

```
public class Devices extends Controller {

private static final Form<Device> deviceForm = Form.form(Device.class);

public static Result details(Device device) {
    if (device == null) {
        return notFound(String.format("Device does not exist. "));
    }
    Form<Device> filledForm = deviceForm.fill(device);
    return ok(views.html.devices.details.render(filledForm));
}


public static Result save() {
    Form<Device> boundForm = deviceForm.bindFromRequest();
    ...
    [here]
    ...
}
}
```

note: details method will show the user the filled form, user may or may not change the values, and then by pressing a Save button , the save() method will be called.

Comment: And for what? To check that the currently entered device exists? Then you can also use an AJAX request.

Comment: There's no simple solution for this, there are some possibilities, but they vary on what de facto you need to perform this check.

Comment: Im not good with AJAX so I tried to find other solutions. finally I came up with a more complex solution without using the Form object. So for now I have what i was looking for. thanks for the comments

but it would be great if I could just simply say something like: boolean nameChanged = boundForm.hasChanged("name");

Comment: I'm really curious  what is the case - that you need to know if name changed, - just wondering if avoiding Form isn't too big price in your case, can you elaborate shortly ?

Comment: Using AJAX is very easy with Play and there should be some tutorials available. And I recommend using that, instead of breaking the "rules" for a RESTful service.

Comment: thanks @Tom, I will try to do some validations with Ajax in the future. seems to be easy. you are right, what I am looking for, is Stateful and against RESTful "rules".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shortest words `Form<T>` isn't able to check if fields are changed it's just *stateless* between request and to check it you just need to get record from DB and compare field, by field.

Also you shouldn't rely on *client-side* validation as it's mainly for **cosmetic**, NOT for safety. Remember that it can be manipulated or omitted quite easy with common webdev tools.

Finally you shouldn't resign from `Form` validation possibilities,as it's very handy tool, instead you can cooperate with it, i.e. it can be something like:

```
public static Result save() {
    Form<Device> boundForm = deviceForm.bindFromRequest();
    if (boundForm.hasErrors()){
        return badRequest(devices.details.render(boundForm));
    }

    Device boundDevice = boundForm.get();
    Device existingDevice = Device.find.byId(boundDevice.id);

    if (boundDevice.name.equals(existingDevice.name)){
        boundForm.reject("Contents are identical");
        return badRequest(devices.details.render(boundForm));
    }

    // else... form hasn't errors, name changed - should be updated...
    boundDevice.update(boundDevice.id);
}
```

So you can display it in your view i.e.:

```
@if(yourForm.error("identicalContent")!=null) {
    <div class="alert alert-danger">@yourForm.error("identicalContent").message</div>
}
```

As you can see from this sample - if you want just to skip `UPDATE` query if no changes - to save resources - it does not make sense, as you need to make `SELECT` query anyway to compare. In other cases (like i.e. additional logging ONLY if changed) above snippet is correct solution.

Comment: Thank you @biesior for your answer, my Model (Device) is a bit more complicated than what I wrote in the question. as you mentioned, I am doing a lot of validations inside my controller in order to make sure that the data is acceptable. (I think I need to redesign my model's key attributes, in order to make things nicer.)

by the way, you mentioned that the client side validation is not safe, what exactly do you mean with client side validation? Ajax?

Comment: Yes, in very general I mean AJAX

Comment: P.S. I agree with @Tom - that building AJAX applications with Play is quite nice and efficient, i.e. there are nice video tuts Play+Angular, anyway nevermind as good the JS framework is - even if has great validators, final validation must be done in your server-side controller.